# Unexpected time results in sequential vs parallel code

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, parallel-processing, c++17

I'm working on a project using OpenCV, where I apply a filter to an image and measure the time it takes for this process. I then collect the top 1% of the best results among different algorithms. However, I'm facing an issue where the execution times of the sequential and parallel algorithms seem contradictory.

The algorithms are being executed in the `color_rgb.simd.hpp` file in the `cvtBGRtoGray` function at line 1233. To measure the time, I used high_resolution_clock.

This is the sequential code:

```
uchar media;
long last_byte = (width * height) * 3;
for (long i = 0, j = 0; i < last_byte; i += 3, j++) {
    media = (src_data[i] + src_data[i+1] + src_data[i+2]) / 3;
    dst_data[j] = media;
}
```

And this is the parallel code:

```
const ponto *inicio = reinterpret_cast<const ponto*>(src_data);
const ponto *fim = reinterpret_cast<const ponto*>(src_data + (( width * height) * 3));
uchar *destino = dst_data;

std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, inicio, fim, destino, [](const ponto &p) {
    uchar media = (p.r + p.g + p.b) / 3;
    return media;
});
```

I conducted tests with different-sized images. However, here are the results for a 256x256 pixel image:

```
Sequential Algorithm: 10,388 ns
Parallel Algorithm: 10,834 ns
```

However, here are the results for a 625x615 pixel image:

```
Sequential Algorithm: 63,999 ns
Parallel Algorithm: 62,299 ns
```

However, here are the results for a 1920x1080 pixel image:

```
Sequential Algorithm: 323,428 ns
Parallel Algorithm: 327,229 ns
```

However, here are the results for a 7680x4320 pixel image:

```
Sequential Algorithm: 8,641,884 ns
Parallel Algorithm: 8,782,140 ns
```

However, here are the results for a 15,360x8,640 pixel image:

```
Sequential Algorithm: 35,218,707 ns
Parallel Algorithm: 35,070,783 ns
```

The test results are surprising because the parallel algorithm takes longer than the sequential one, which seems contradictory. When the situation is reversed, there is no significant optimization. I would like to understand why this is happening and if there is any optimization I can make to improve the performance of the parallel algorithm.

Any ideas about what might be causing this discrepancy in execution times? I appreciate any help or guidance in advance.

I run test with other algorithms : tbb, OpenMP and use pthread. And the results were better than the sequential code. the only algorithm that made suspicious of the result is the parallel code.

Comment: Did you try with `std::execution::par` too? You could also try to use `std::for_each` instead of `std::transform`. The execution policies may not be implemented in all algorithms.

Comment: No, didn't try std::execution::par or std::for_each. I did a pre-selection of the different algoritms i wanted to use, so my work does a refletion on the types that i select.

Comment: Ok, I see, did you link with `tbb` or what library is used as a backend? Did you do an optimized build? Did you enable optimization for the native architecture (`-march=native`)? It's also important to compare algorithms with the data stored in a similar way. I made a test program that you could run that tests all policies: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rKd7xWcfP).  When given a `sequenced_policy` it runs an algorithm like your regular for-loop, otherwise it uses `std::transform` with the supplied policy.

Comment: The differences in times you see are measurement noise. It looks to me that your “parallel” code is sequential too.

Comment: @CrisLuengo My tests are definitely running the algorithms in parallel and I get some consistent differences in the timings, but not as large as one would hope. With such a small `struct` as `ponto` there will be a lot of false sharing so I'm not sure one can do much better. For me, when compiling my test program with `-O3 -march=native`, the `parallel_policy` seems best over all, except for small sizes where the naive sequenced policy is better.

Comment: When running [this program](https://godbolt.org/z/9TTnv1W6r) with the indicated compiler options, I get [these results](https://pastebin.com/7sfb0izx).

Comment: I noticed however that unlike when I've used the execution policies before, most CPUs are idle 99% of the time. I'm usually not satisfied until they are all at 0% idle :-)

Comment: Note that `high_resolution_clock` should not be used in this case. This is [mentioned in the doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

Comment: i didn't link with tbb. i can show the configuration of the compile when i do the build. Building file: ../src/Teste_1.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++17 -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -O3 -g3 -pg -fsanitize=leak -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Teste_1.d" -MT"src/Teste_1.o" -o "src/Teste_1.o" "../src/Teste_1.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Teste_1.cpp

Comment: for the linker , this is outpput: Building file: ../src/Teste_1.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -pg -o "Teste_1" ./src/Teste_1.o    -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_photo -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann
Finished building target: Teste_1

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I thought that the compiler/linker would complain if a back-end library was needed for parallel execution policies.  Can I use other back-end libraries (besides tbb) with the g++?  Which?

Comment: @ManuelMendes I'm unsure. When it comes to execution policies, I think implementations are allowed to fallback on a sequenced policy in all cases.